# Efficient way of counting True and False

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, counting

This may be a trivial problem, but I want to learn more about other more clever and efficient ways of solving it.

I have a list of items and each item has a property `a` whose value is binary.

- If every item in the list has `a == 0`, then I set a separate variable `b = 0`.
- If every item in the list has `a == 1`, then I set `b = 1`.
- If there is a mixture of `a == 0` and `a == 1` in the list, then I set
  `b = 2`.

I can use a set to keep track of the types of `a` value, such that if there are two items in the set after iterating through the list, then I can set `b = 2`, whereas if there is only one item in the set I just retrieve the item (either 0 or 1) and use it to set `b`.

Any better way?

Comment: "Better" is subjective here and also depends a little on which of the 3 cases you expect to hit most often and it may even depend on the length of the list, etc.

Comment: @mgilson, good points. I do not know which case(s) will come up more often than other and the property `a` is set based on input from users. I do know the length of the list will be short, i.e. <= 1000 items.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggest using `any` and `all`. I would say that the benefit of this is readability rather than cleverness or efficiency. For example:

```
>>> vals0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> vals1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> vals2 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
>>> def category(vals):
...     if all(vals):
...         return 1
...     elif any(vals):
...         return 2
...     else:
...         return 0
... 
>>> category(vals0)
0
>>> category(vals1)
1
>>> category(vals2)
2
```

This can be shortened a bit if you like:

```
>>> def category(vals):
...     return 1 if all(vals) else 2 if any(vals) else 0
...
```

This works with anything that can be interpreted by `__nonzero__` (or `__bool__` in Python 3) as having a true or false value.

Comment: +1 Exactly the answer I would have posted a couple of minutes before you if my ISP hadn't decided to die. :-) (except the one-liner, which is code golf).

Comment: nah, it's not code golf, can you see that horribly long parameter name?

Answer (score 26):

One pass through the list, and no extra data structures constructed:

```
def zot(bs):
    n, s = len(bs), sum(bs)
    return 1 if n == s else 2 if s else 0
```

Comment: nice.  what does zot mean? zero-one-two?

Comment: This draws attention to the corner case `bs == []`. It's interesting that our solutions handle it the same way (`zot` and `category` both return `1`), but I'm not certain whether that's the correct response. `all([])` returns `True`, while `any([])` returns `False`, so if I had organized my if statement differently, `category([])` would have returned `0`.

Comment: I think the problem statement is contradictory then:  for an empty input, it's trivially true that all are 0, and that all are 1.  So we return the sum of the two correct answers ;-)

Comment: This is so absurdly clever. Is this how core developers think on a daily basis? This approach would not have occurred to me in a thousand years.

Comment: Ah, but the *next* time you see a problem like this, it will occur to you.  Multiply that by some decades, and your bag of tricks becomes large ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Somebody mentioned code golf, so can't resist a variation on @senderle's:

```
[0,2,1][all(vals) + any(vals)]
```

*Short explanation*: This uses the boolean values as their integer equivalents to index a list of desired responses. If `all` is true then `any` must also be true, so their sum is `2`. `any` by itself gives `1` and no matches gives `0`. These indices return the corresponding values from the list.

If the original requirements could be modified to use `1` for `any` and `2` for `all` it would be even simpler to just return the integer of `any + all`

Answer (score 3):

Using a dictionary:

```
zonk_values = {frozenset([0]): 0, frozenset([1]): 1, frozenset([0, 1]): 2}
def zonk(a):
    return zonk_values[frozenset(a)]
```

This also only needs a single pass through the list.

Comment: True, it's one-pass, but it visits every object in the list and builds a `frozenset` while doing so.

Answer (score 2):

you could also use sets.

```
s = set([i.a for i in your_list])
if len(s) == 1:
    b = s.pop()
else:
    b = 2
```

Comment: A set object does not support indexing. Use `next(iter(s))`. Also, why the `i.a`?

Comment: i.a was simply a pull the a values out of the list of objects as indicated in the question:

"I have a list of items and each item has a property a whose value is binary."

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment Noctua.  Sets DON'T support indexing.  I was also seeing some strange behavior with the inline conditional and removed it.  I think I like the any/all answer the best

Answer (score 2):

```
def zot(bs):
    return len(set(bs)) if sum(bs) else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define two boolean vars `hasZero` and `hasOne` and set them to `True` if corresponding value was met while iterating the list. Then `b = 2` if `hasZero and hasOne`, `b = 1` if only `hasOne` and `b = 0` if only `hasZero`.

Another way: you can sum all the `a` values along the list. If `sumA == len(list)` then `b = 1`, if `sumA == 0` then `b = 0` and if `0 < sumA < len(list)` then `b = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Short-circuiting solution. Probably the most efficient way you can do it in Python.

EDIT: Included `any` and `all` as per suggestion in comments.

EDIT2: It's now a one-liner.

```
b = 1 if all(A) else 2 if any(A) else 0
```

Comment: The built-in `any()` and `all()` functions short-circuit and are likely faster than any explicit loop-through-the-items.

Comment: @martineau Explicit for-looping is implemented in C, just the same as `any` and `all`. I don't see why iteration would be any slower than your methods.

Comment: The looping is not implemented in C the same way.

Comment: @martineau Okay, I'll defer. I edited my answer to do `any` and `all`.

Comment: All off CPython is implemented in C.  The difference is that executing the `for` loop involves interpretation of bytecode within the loop, while calls to `all()` and `any()` don't.  On my machine, a manual implementation of `any()` applied to a big list is about three times slower than the built-in version.

Comment: Convince yourself by using the `timeit` module.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to senderle's suggestion, but written to access the objects' `a` properties.

```
from random import randint

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

all_zeros = [Item(0) for _ in xrange(10)]
all_ones = [Item(1) for _ in xrange(10)]
mixture = [Item(randint(0, 1)) for _ in xrange(10)]

def check(items):
    if all(item.a for item in items):
        return 1
    if any(item.a for item in items):
        return 2
    else:
        return 0

print 'check(all_zeros):', check(all_zeros)
print 'check(all_ones):', check(all_ones)
print 'check(mixture):', check(mixture)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list `iter`ators:

```
>>> L = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> L1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> L2 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
>>> def fn(i):
...     i = iter(i)
...     if all(i): return 1
...     return 2 if any(i) else 0
... 
>>> fn(L)
0
>>> fn(L1)
1
>>> fn(L2)
2
```